# Mongo DB Radius Units for GeoQuerys

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I am trying to work out what unit MongoDB queries use...

I have the following query:

```
User.objects(address__point__geo_within_center=[[lat, long],maxDistance])
```

I would like to user meters e.g. 10 meters within maxDistance.

But in the documention (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/center/#op._S_center) it says

> "The circle’s radius, as measured in the units used by the coordinate
>   system"

I can not find a reference to "units" anywhere?

I have been using http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html for ref.

What are the units?

Can i set the units?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to use $center which is only supported by the 2d index. You should be using the 2dshpere index and its supported operations. For that, the [2dsphere docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/) is a good place to start.

The [$nearSphere](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/#op._S_nearSphere) geospatial query operator should do what you want. Note that operator uses distance in **meters**.

The [mongoengine docs](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#geo-queries) show a geo_within_sphere operator, which is probably what you want.